# Has anyone made import functionality to Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

We need to import hundreds of users to Keycloak from csv-file. I haven't found any ready-made import functionality to do this.

Has anyone made any import routine or at least some skeleton to build on? REST API is probably the only way to do it - or is there another way?

Comment: Did you succeed in any way?

Comment: We haven't done it yet but seems that we have to write some code to make the import. There is not much community around Keycloak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've recently build something like that in Java. You can use the REST Api, but there is also the admin-client. See [Programmatically adding users in Keycloak](http://www.first8.nl/blog/programmatically-adding-users-in-keycloak/) for some pointers. It should be trivial to add CSV support for that using e.g. [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Basically you can add a Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And use it like this:

```
Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance(
  "http://localhost:8080/auth", 
  "master", // the realm to log in to
  "admin", "password",  // the user
  "security-admin-console");

CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
credential.setValue("test123");
UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
user.setUsername("testuser");
user.setFirstName("Test");
user.setLastName("User");
user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
kc.realm("master").users().create(user);
```

Comment: Brilliant! That seems exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it out.